# difference between terminate stay resident and interrupt service routine concepts and syntax

Tags: assembly

I am highly not being able to understand in the difference between terminate stay resident  and interrupt service routine code syntax and some concepts. i am studying computer organisation assembly language. I have this code, and please tell me whether i am correctly recognizing the tsr and isr? (i am having exam right after 3 hrs.)

is that tsr?

```
.model tiny
.data
        msg db "You can't divide a number by zero$"
.code

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

        mov ax,0
        mov es,ax

        mov bx,offset isr
        mov es:[0h*4],bx
        mov es:[0h*4+2],cs

        mov ah,31h
        int 21h

        isr proc far

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax

        mov ah,9h
        lea dx,msg
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h

        iret
        isr endp

       end
```

is that isr?

```
.model small
.data 

     msg db "UCP$"
     oldisr dd ?

.code

    main proc

    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    mov ax,0
    mov es,ax

    mov bx,es:[21h*4]
    mov oldisr,bx

    mov bx,es:[21h*4+2]
    mov [oldisr+2],bx

    mov bx,offset myproc
    mov es:[21h*4],bx

    mov es:[21h*4+2],cs

    mov dx,offset msg 


    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h




     hlt   

        main endp



    myproc proc far

       cmp ah,9h
       jne l1
       mov ah,4ch
       jmp l2
       l1:
       cmp ah,4ch
       jne l2
       mov ah,9h
       l2:

       pushf
       call far ds:[oldisr]

       iret

    myproc endp

    end
```

Comment: Assuming that this is running under MSDOS. Terminate and stay resident just leaves your program in memory after exiting. It looks like your hooking into the interrupt vector ok, but your interrupt code should probably not use any INT 21h dos calls, and it definately should not use the dos exit (ah = 04ch, INT 21H).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two related concepts; they often go together, but not necessarily. Don't let the name similarity confuse you.

ISR means "Interrupt service routine". That means - it's a piece of code that is invoked when an interrupt occurs (normally hardware-driven, i. e. timer or keyboard, but not necessarily). ISRs in real mode systems (like MS-DOS) are listed in the interrupt table at address 0000:0000. There are 256 interrupt vectors - that is, far addresses of interrupt handlers. You can change one of them to an address in your own program. But there's the catch: normally, when the program terminates, the address range it used to occupy is returned to the OS and OS is free to use it for something else. Here's where the concept of TSR comes in.

TSR stands for "Terminate and stay resident". That means - a program is done running, but its code and data remains in memory. This is implemented in DOS via int 21h, function 31h. When a program hooks up an interrupt vector and does not restore it to the original value at the end, it better stay resident - otherwise the vector value will go invalid once the program is unloaded.

So, to recap: TSR is a method of terminating a program that doesn't unload it. Sometimes the word is used for the program itself. ISR is a routine (function, procedure, etc.) within that program that gains control when an interrupt is invoked, via an interrupt vector.

It's possible to have an ISR in a program that doesn't stay resident; but in this case, the vector hookup may only last while the program executes. Before termination, it should restore the vector to the original value; otherwise, the next attempt to execute that interrupt would crash the system.

It's also possible to have a TSR program that doesn't hook any interrupts and therefore has no ISRs. But there's very little point to that. DOS doesn't provide any other universally accepted means of TSR program reactivation.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an incredibly old question, that has been voted down through the floor, and is worded nearly unintelligibly, but what I think you're asking is:

a) What is the difference between a TSR and an ISR?

b) Is one of these programs a TSR and the other an ISR?

The answer to B is no. They are both TSRs. The second one just installs its ISR manually, and exits via the DOS2.0+ exit call (with return value, AH=4Ch), instead of the DOS1.0+ exit call (without return value, AH=0), and the second installs via the DOS 2.0+ **T**erminate and **S**tay **R**esident call (AH=31h).

The answer to A is that the ISR (**I**nterrupt **S**ervice **R**outine) is installed by the TSR, and is the part of the program which **S**tays **R**esident after the rest of the program has **T**erminated.

So, an ISR is an **I**nterrupt **S**ervice **R**outine, which services interrupts, and is the part that is installed by the TSR program before it **T**erminates, and **S**tays **R**esident.

I know OP will probably never see this (with the post being 4 years old), but I guess if anyone else has more questions, feel free to reply.